# How to Move Map in Background with Fixed Marker Pin in Carto Mobile Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cartodb, carto-mobile

I want to fix the marker in the center of the map and when user move map, marker don't change position in Carto Mobile SDK. I want change size marker when map moved begin(touch begin), and resize to first size when end map moved(touch end)(resize effect for marker when map moved)

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have such Marker in MapView itself directly. I would try to add another transparent view on top of MapView, and make sure that the view does not get the touches. You can manipulate/animate it any way you like, and get center location coordinates from MapView.